# JSF 2.0; "argument type mismatch" from custom data type class?

Tags: jsf-2, illegalargumentexception

I'm going to create a custom data type for my input fields. (see clas "Amount").
Setting the value in the inputfield "amountId" does work perfect. But, if i want to submit the form and go to another page, then i've got the "argument type mismatch" exception.

Can someone explain me, why i get this exception?

- Do i need a converter to convert the input value to string?
- Have i forgot some methods in my Amount class to implement, which JSF needs to get the values?

Here is my code:

```
public class Amount implements Serializable {
    public Amount(BigDecimal bd){
    }

    public Amount(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    }
}



@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
    @RequestScoped
    public class MyBean extends BaseBean {
        private Amount amountValue;
        private UIInput amountValueId;

        public Amount getAmountValue() {
            return amountValue;
        }

        public void setAmountValue(Amount amountValue) {
            this.amountValue = amountValue;
            if (this.amountValueId != null)
                this.amountValueId.setSubmittedValue(amountValue);
        }

        public UIInput getAmountValueIdId() {
            return amountValueId;
        }

        public void setAmountValueId(UIInput amountValueId) {
            this.amountValueId = amountValueId
        }
    }



<h:inputText id="amountValueId" binding="#{myBean.amountValueId}" size="30" value="#{myBean.amountValue}" />




javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)


org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.setValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:166)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:406)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:328)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:263)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1469)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1469)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1469)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._processUpdatesDefault(UIViewRoot.java:1397)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.access$600(UIViewRoot.java:74)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$UpdateModelPhaseProcessor.process(UIViewRoot.java:1535)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1358)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:806)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesExecutor.execute(UpdateModelValuesExecutor.java:38)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
```

Comment: I think you should add converter to your <h:inputText  take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/  cause your trying to submit string into Amount object

Comment: Oh, a converter helped me :) thanks alot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should add converter to your `<h:inputText` take a look at this [Custom converter in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/) cause your trying to submit `String` into `Amount` object